# Make Line chart gradient color go from line to bottom - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, charts, colors, swiftui

I am trying to make it so the line chart display a gradient color from the line and down but I can't seem to get it to only go from the line. Instead it just fills the whole background in the given frame.

I have this - [Graph current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkap4.png)

But I would like this - [Graph wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKvhL.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct Graph: View {

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        
        LineGraph(dataPoints: [1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 1])
            .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2784313725, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 2)

    }
    .frame(width: 124, height: 90, alignment: .center)
    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4901960784, green: 0.5058823529, blue: 0.9803921569, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
  }

}


struct LineGraph: Shape {

var dataPoints: [CGFloat]

func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    
    func point(at ix: Int) -> CGPoint {
        let point = dataPoints[ix]
        let x = rect.width * CGFloat(ix) / CGFloat(dataPoints.count - 1)
        let y = (1 - point) * rect.height
        
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
    
    return Path { p in
        
        guard dataPoints.count > 1 else {return}
        
        let start = dataPoints[0]
        p.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: (1 - start) * rect.height))
        
        for index in dataPoints.indices {
            p.addLine(to: point(at: index))
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is possible solution - use same graph for clipped background (we need closed path for that) and another variant for stroked line.

Prepared with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
struct Graph: View {
    let dataPoints: [CGFloat] = [1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 1]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            LinearGradient(gradient:
                Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4901960784, green: 0.5058823529, blue: 0.9803921569, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .clipShape(LineGraph(dataPoints: dataPoints, closed: true))  // << !!

            LineGraph(dataPoints: dataPoints)
                .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2784313725, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 2)
        }
        .frame(width: 124, height: 90, alignment: .center)
    }
    
}


struct LineGraph: Shape {
    var dataPoints: [CGFloat]
    var closed = false        // << indicator for variants !!
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        func point(at ix: Int) -> CGPoint {
            let point = dataPoints[ix]
            let x = rect.width * CGFloat(ix) / CGFloat(dataPoints.count - 1)
            let y = (1 - point) * rect.height
            
            return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        }
        
        return Path { p in
            
            guard dataPoints.count > 1 else {return}
            
            let start = dataPoints[0]
            p.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: (1 - start) * rect.height))
            
            for index in dataPoints.indices {
                p.addLine(to: point(at: index))
            }

            if closed {   // << variant for clipping !!
                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
                p.closeSubpath()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add plot points to this?